# Android: force a thread to close and display an alert dialog

Tags: android, multithreading, dialog, alert

I have a thread inside which I catch an exception. What I want is that when this happens, the thread closes/quits/dies or whatever I should say, and an alert dialog is displayed (no like toasts!).

Here's my code:

```
    t1 = new Thread(new Runnable()
    {   
        public void run() 
        {
            Looper.prepare();
            StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer("");
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
            URI uri = null;

            try
            {
                requestAndMakeSheet(stringBuffer, bufferedReader, uri);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Web Request Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //Log.e("Web Request Error", e.getMessage());
                t1.interrupt();
                AlertDialog.Builder parsingErrorBox = new AlertDialog.Builder(ReservationInfo.this);
                parsingErrorBox.setTitle("Login error");
                parsingErrorBox.setMessage("You may have to check your credentials and then try again.");
                parsingErrorBox.show();
            }
            finally
            {
                if (bufferedReader!=null)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        bufferedReader.close();
                    }
                    catch (IOException ioe)
                    {
                        Log.e("Web Request Error", ioe.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            }
        }           
    });
    t1.start();
    try 
    {
        t1.join();
        mWebview.loadUrl("file:///"+Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/MySheet.html");
        setContentView(mWebview);
    } 
    catch (InterruptedException e) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //End of le thread
}
```

This code crashes, I think it has something to do with t1.interrupt (tried stop instead, but didn't work either).

How can I fix this code?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Post your LogCat errors, it often explains exactly what happened. Also you should go through your old questions and accept the best answers, people volunteer their time to help you please "repay" them with this simple gesture.

Comment: 12-15 01:27:34.619: W/HardwareRenderer(14911): Attempting to initialize hardware acceleration outside of the main thread, aborting
12-15 01:28:34.404: I/dalvikvm(14911): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
12-15 01:28:34.474: I/dalvikvm(14911): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'

That's all it says. But I have plenty of things happening wrong in my app. The file is supposed not to be displayed in the webview when requestAndMakeSheet throws an exception, but actually it does load it (it loads the prior file join()). Also, when it throws the exception, the activity freezes!

Comment: You can always walk through you code line-by-line with the debugger to narrow down the source of the problem. You can also a `e.printStackTrace()` inside your catch block to see the error details. All that aside, what is `requestAndMakeSheet()`?

Comment: I can't use the debugger, it's bugged itself! If I try to step into the thread, it says "Class File Editor - Source not found for ClassLoader.class"!!!

Comment: Ok, I managed to bypass the debugger's errors by changing my breakpoints and putting them inside the thread. requestAndMakeSheet is a huge function that uses jSoup to parse an HTML file. What it does, is throw an exception when jSoup doesn't find some of the elements of the page, what happens when the login and/or password entered by the user is incorrect.

I removed the t1.interrupt() in my code but what happens now is that when the exception is thrown, the alert dialog doesn't show, the webView displays "webpage not available" and the app freezes completely. :(

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have the t1.interrupt() anyway? Seems like your thread will be terminated regardless so what is the reason for putting it there?

Comment: Because I thought if I didn't, the message box would never show up.